# How to access parent block's attributes in nested block's save function?

Tags: block-editor

I currently have a block that passes some of its `attributes` down to the nested `InnerBlocks` using React's Context API (the version of WordPress that I'm on does not yet have the [Block Context](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-context/) feature. This allows me to successfully access the parent block's `attributes` in the nested blocks' `edit` function.

```
registerBlockType("myblock", {
  title: "My Block",
  attributes: {
    someValue: {
      type: 'string',
      default: '',
    },
  },
  edit(props) {
    const { someValue } = props.attributes;

    // ...other code...

    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={someValue}>
        <InnerBlocks />
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
  },
  save(props) {
    const { someValue } = props.attributes;

    return (
      <InnerBlocks.Content />
    );
  }
});
```

However, I also want to access the parent block's attributes in the `save` function of the nested blocks. I have not been able to get React's Context API to work. Is there a method for doing this in WordPress's Block API?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass data to a child via the select and dispatch hooks. So you would set up your child block with the inherited attribute and update that when the setting on the parent block changes.

**Parent Block**

Import dependencies

```
import { dispatch, select } from "@wordpress/data";
```

Your edit function might look something like this:

```
edit({ attributes, className, setAttributes, clientId }) {
    const { headerStyle } = attributes;

    const updateHeaderStyle = function( value ) {
        setAttributes({ headerStyle: value });

        // Update the child block's attributes
        var children = select('core/block-editor').getBlocksByClientId(clientId)[0].innerBlocks;
        children.forEach(function(child){
            dispatch('core/block-editor').updateBlockAttributes(child.clientId, {inheritedHeaderStyle: value})
        });
    }
    

    return (
        <>
            <InspectorControls>
                <PanelBody>
          

                    <RadioControl
                        label="Section Header Style"
                        selected = {headerStyle}
                        options = { [
                            { label: 'h2', value: 'h2' },
                            { label: 'h3', value: 'h3' },
                            { label: 'h4', value: 'h4' },
                            { label: 'h5', value: 'h5' },
                            { label: 'h6', value: 'h6' },
                        ]}
                        onChange= {updateHeaderStyle}
                    />
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>
            <InnerBlocks
              ...
            />
         <>
  );
  }
```

**Child Block**

The above function will update on change, but within the edit function of the child block you can grab the parent attribute and set it if undefined...

```
if (!inheritedHeaderStyle) {
    var parent = select('core/block-editor').getBlockParents(clientId);
    const parentAtts = select('core/block-editor').getBlockAttributes(parent);
    setAttributes( { inheritedHeaderStyle: parentAtts.headerStyle } )
}
```

Comment: ok. watching this answer a 20th time i now finally realize, what is happening here. you use the parent element to set the attribute to itself AND to its children. got this working on my end, finally <3

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use build in feature `Context`.

**Parent Block**

```
registerBlockType( 'my-plugin/parent', {
 
    attributes: {
        switch: {
            type: 'boolean',
            default:false
        },
    },
 
    providesContext: {
        'my-plugin/switch': 'switch',
    },

    edit: Edit,

    save,
} );
```

**Child Block**

```
registerBlockType( 'my-plugin/child', {
     attributes: {
        switch: {
            type: 'boolean',
            default:false
        },
    },

    usesContext: [ 'my-plugin/switch' ],
 
    edit({ attributes, setAttributes, context }) {

        // copy value from parent context into child attribute
        setAttributes({
          switch: context["my-plugin/switch"],
        });
    },
 
    save({ attributes }) {

        // use this attribute
        
    },
} );
```

API Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-context/

Comment: As written, this causes problems when initializing the block in the editor because `setAttributes()` modifies the component's state, which should not happen during rendering. You can fix this by wrapping the `setAttributes` call inside `useEffect()`:
`useEffect( () => {  setAttributes({ switch: context['my-plugin/switch'] }); }, [context, setAttributes]);`